# How do I delete a log file while using RollingFileAppender in log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Sometimes, while rolling log files, there seems to be some issue occurring like: 'Unable to delete log file', 'Unable to move log file'.

```
Error: java.nio.file.FileSystemException a.log -> directory\a-2011-08-09-2.log: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Following is the log4j configuration:

```
<RollingFile name="a" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/a.log" append="true" createOnDemand="true" filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/a-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{ISO8601}|%-5p|%i|%T|%s|%R|%t|%c{1} - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="25"/>
        </RollingFile>
```

Comment: I know that catalina.out is kept open by tomcat and so logrotate needs to use copyOnTruncate flag, but I am not sure if this is in any way related to your problem

Comment: You used a forward slash in the path. Are you running on Windows? Have you tried ruling out your AV by turning it off for a while?

Comment: @kichik what is AV ?

Comment: AV is anti virus like Symantec or McAfee.

Comment: how would that affect this issue?

Comment: A lot of Windows AVs have issues with locking files that prevent their deletion.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... Hopefully someone has a good answer. If I figure something out, I'll post my answer.